# UIContentContainer resizes only to bigger values than set before

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a UIContentContainer that changes its child view controllers at runtime. The ContentContainer view controller responds to the:

```
- (void)preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:(id<UIContentContainer>)container
{
    [super preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:container];
     self.contentContainerHeightContstraint.constant = container.preferredContentSize.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
}
```

So when I set the `preferredContentSize` in my childViewController to a bigger size than before the container resizes properly but when I take a smaller value, nothing happens.

I tried to play around with content compression and the hugging priority. No luck so far.

So why is the `preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer` method only getting called when the value is bigger than before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was inside a `UINavigationController` and I had to call the `self.parentViewController.preferredContentSize`. Now it is resizing properly.